# Customize order of "Add new" elements (ALT + Ins)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

Clicking `ALT + Ins` shows a window where we can select what we want to add.

[image]

I was wondering, is there a way to **change the order** of these elements?

In particular, since almost all new classes are in Kotlin, I'd like to have Kotlin as first option, so I won't have to click the down arrow to select it.

Comment: An alternative would be to define a keybinding for "Add new Kotlin file/class" directly, and skip the Alt+Ins part.

Comment: Did you find help?

Answer (score 0):

It works as in [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-menus-and-toolbars.html):

1. Right-click the main toolbar (that's where you can find Run/Debug buttons etc)
2. Choose "Customize Menus and Toolbars"
3. Go into "Navigation Bar" -> "New" (Other views might be desired, such as Projects)
4. Change ordering as you prefer
5. Restart might be needed